# Configure two custom plugins in telegraf

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

I have created a custom plugin and it works well. And dockerize that custom plugin then also it works well.
What I want to do is create one more custom plugin and dockerize that plugin. And set these two dockerize custom plugins in my `telegef.conf` file as input plugins.

Is it possible? If it is possible then how to implement it?
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `execd` input plugin, and have it launch your docker containers running an individual plugin, as long as those containers write their data to STDOUT